# Pass input type text value through URL using $_GET PHP

Tags: php

I have this piece of code, and I want to pass the text of an input type text through URL using `$_GET`.

```
<?php print("
            <tr class='$class'>
              <td>
                <input type='text' name='newName' />
                <a class='rename' href='http://www.example.com/php/rename.php?file=$namehref&new_name=$_GET['$newName']'>
                  <span>Rename</span>
                </a>
              </td>
           ");
?>
```

But this code doesn't work. Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
   //put your php code here and close tag
?>
            <tr class=''>
                <td>
                    <input type='text' name='newName' />
                    <a class='rename' 
                       onclick="var textVal = document.getElementsByName('newName')[0].value; 
                           window.location.href = 'http://www.example.com/php/rename.php?file=<?php echo $namehref;?>&new_name='+textVal"
                       href="javascript:void(0);">
                        <span>Rename</span>
                    </a>
                </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

try change `$_GET['$newName']` to `{$_GET["$newName"]}`:

```
<?php print("
        <tr class='$class'>
            <td>
                <input type='text' name='newName' />
                <a class='rename' href='http://www.example.com/php/rename.php?file=$namehref&new_name={$_GET["$newName"]}'>
                    <span>Rename</span>
                </a>
            </td>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the enclosing `''` around `$newName`:

```
<?php
 print("
    <tr class='$class'>
        <td>
            <input type='text' name='newName' />
            <a class='rename' href='http://www.example.com/php/rename.php?file=$namehref&new_name=$_GET[$newName]'>
                <span>Rename</span>
            </a>
        </td>");
```

Also, you could enclose `$_GET[$newName]` with `{}`, if you absolutely need the `$newName` to be enclosed in quotes (i.e: `{$_GET["$newName"]}`.) More information can be found [here](https://php.net/language.types.string).

Answer (score 0):

This would be a harder code if you use the $_GET[]. I will suggest you to use a javascript to pass the text to other attribute in an element.